# Why does projection behaves differently in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I find this concept little bit confusing. Suppose we have product of projective varieties as $Y = Y_1 \times Y_2 \times \ldots \times Y_n$. I was reading in book that it is not necessary true that if we have subvariety $V \subset Y$, then we don't have $V = \pi_{1}(V) \times \pi_{2}(V) \times \ldots \times \pi_{n}(V)$, where $\pi$ is the projection can someone explain this to me the reason to me. I know there are examples, but I would like to know the deep reason for this. Hartshorne doesn't explain this. I am familiar with first chapter of Hartshorne.

Answer (score 4):

This happens even in the category of sets. Let $S$ be a set, and consider the diagonal $D = \{(x, x) \in S \times S : x \in S\} \subseteq S \times S$. Then, $\pi_1(D) = S, \pi_2(D) = S$ but $D \neq S \times S$.

Similarly, consider the diagonal $\mathbb{P}^1_k \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^1_k$. This is a closed immersion since $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is separated. However, by looking at the dimension,  $\mathbb{P}^1_k $ can't be written as a nontrivial product of varieties.

Comment: To emphasize the point in the first paragraph of this answer: The use of "differently" in the title of the question seems to  be just an error. The behavior you describe occurs not only for algebraic varieties and (as the answer points out) for sets but also for topological spaces (and similar categories like smooth manifolds) and for groups (and similar algebraic categories). It's quite typical for projections to behave in this way.